# How to call similar named fields using a forloop

Tags: c#

I have made 20 objects , lets say, pictureBoxes.
pictureBox1
pictureBox2
pictureBox3
etc.

How can I edit these object is an automated way?
I want to do somthing like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < boxcount; i++){
pictureBox[i].somevalue = true;
}
```

How can I make it so that for example the name pictureBox1.visible is generated?

*I have tried using:*

*picturebox +i*

Comment: Instead of having multiple pictureBoxes, Have an array/`List<T>` or any other collection.

Comment: Could you show an example for users like me?

Comment: Also if you downvote please tell me why, i wont revenge vote. i want to improve my self!

Comment: Not sure why downvoted, seems like it was explained what was needed and what was tried pretty well

Comment: maybe it was downvoted because this is a question you could google and likely find your answer. I didn't downvote myself but I always attempt a thorough google search before asking a question

Comment: @Peterverleg, I didn't downvote, probably it got downvoted  because people consider it some what basic, which I think is wrong.

Comment: You can do it via reflection. But I would also suggest doing it from an array or List

Comment: You could also iterate the controls property of parent container,or use the tag property to name the pictureBoxes..there are a lot of ways to do it, but i would go the List<T> way also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use code to generate the name of a variable and then dereference that variable. Instead, store the variables in an array and iterate over it:

```
PictureBox[] boxes = {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4};

foreach(var box in boxes)
{
  box.somevalue = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBoxes>() { new PictureBoxes {}, new PictureBoxes };

 foreach (var pb in pictureBoxes)
 {
    pb.Somevalue = "blah";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of picture boxes like this. `List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBoxes>();`

Then in a loop add the boxes to the list. You can then access like `pictureBoxes[x]`

loop would be something like:

```
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBoxes>(); 
for(int i=0; i < #of boxes you want; i++)
{
    pictureBoxes.add(pictureBox(Your params that change));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Linq*; if all the `PictureBox` of interest are put on the form you can implement somthing like this

```
  var boxes = Controls
    .OfType<PictureBox>()
    .Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(item.Name, "^pictureBox[0-9]+$"));

  foreach (var box in boxes)
    boxes.SomeValue = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative if pictureboxes are all in the same container:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
     if (c is PictureBox)
     {
          c.BackColor = Color.Red;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this on WinForms (which it seems that you are) you could put this on the control that contains the picture boxes:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= boxCount; i++)
{
    var b1 = $"pictureBox{i}";
    var b = this.Controls.Find(b1, false).First();
    b.Visible = false;
}
```

You need to find the controls on the base controls and this does not check the children of the children of each control on the base control but this is what could get you what you want.